# Работа с текстовыми файлами VC++

Tags: visual-c++, файлы

При добавлении текста в файл открываю файл с помощью метода

```
StreamWriter^ sw = File::AppendText("testworkfile.txt");
```

Затем начинаю добавлять информацию в файл с помощью

```
sw->WriteLine("какая то информация");
```

все отлично за исключением того что метод после последней введенной строки создает еще одну пустую строку, в файле выглядит это примерно так:

```
    информация
    информация
    информация
    |   <- пустая строка
```

Прошу ответить на следующие вопросы:

1. Возможно ли как то запретить функции `WriteLine()` добавлять пустую строку?
2. Если нет то можно ли как нибудь редактировать файл без полной перезаписи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дописывая последнюю строку, вызывайте метод `Write` вместо `WriteLine`.

Comment: Все работает спасибо большое